# Are there any federal laws in the United States regulating non-digital billboards?

Tags: united-states

Billboards can be quite a distraction to drivers, and [some cities have banned digital billboards](http://usatoday30.usatoday.com/news/nation/2010-03-22-visual-soup_N.htm). However, I haven't been able to find any information on non-digital billboards, which don't seem to be significantly less distracting in many cases.

Are there any federal laws regulating non-digital billboards to lessen distractions for drivers?

I ask for federal laws because of applications to interstate highways. I don't know if any regulations would be applied by states or by the federal government, since billboards by the boundary of a state can distract drivers on both sides of the state line.

Answer (score 5):

For interstate and federal highways at least, there are regulations.  For example, [the billboards in Times Square are illegal](http://www.metro.us/new-york/times-square-without-billboards/zsJoed---rP5clYN58layE/).

> But it turns out this billboard, and others plastering Times Square, may actually be illegal. Under a federal highway beautification law, the billboards are too big – the law states that [billboards] should not be larger than 1200 square feet.
>
> Last week, the city’s transportation commissioner said the billboards may have to be taken down, or New York could risk losing ten percent of its federal highway funds.

The [Highway Beautification Act](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/23/131) and various amendments can be referenced [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highway_Beautification_Act).